# Rolling Correlation For Loop

Tags: pandas, loops, dataframe

I want to find the **rolling correlation** between each series in my dataframe and one particular series in that dataframe  but I keep receiving a key error when running the loop.

It should be noted that all dataframes shown in the code below have the same row length.

Also note that when I explicitly call a series to run that one particular series with it runs fine.

It seems to be the for loop where there is an issue.

```
df_list_abbrev=pd.DataFrame()
df_list_abbrev['max']=df_corr_sq_metrics.max(axis=1).sort_values(ascending=False)
df_list_abbrev['min']=df_corr_sq_metrics.min(axis=1).sort_values(ascending=True)
x=pd.DataFrame()
x=pd.concat([df_list_abbrev['max'].head(10),df_list_abbrev['min'].head(10)],axis=0)
x=list(x.index) 
df_list_roll_corr=pd.DataFrame(pd.concat([df_list[x],df_name],axis=1))
df_name=df_name.reset_index()
df_name=df_name.iloc[:, 2:len(df_name)+1]

for k in df_list_roll_corr.columns:
    df_roll_corr[f'{k}']=df_list_roll_corr['chg_VIX_shift_level_-1'].rolling(20).corr(df_list_roll_corr[f'{k}'])
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please review [ask] and create a [mcve]

Comment: why are you using f strings? using `df_roll_corr[k]`  should work

Comment: @Yuca because ideally I would want to include additional strings to name the newly created series.

Comment: bottom line your error means that you're asking for a column that does not exist, try to check the contents of `df_list_roll_corr` before running the correlation